# how to draw google earth image over an existing plot

Tags: r, plot, google-earth

I'm able to download the image I want from Google Earth inside R:

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map(c(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2),maptype="satellite")
```

I can see the image using

```
ggmap(map)
```

But I want to add it to an existing plot, as with "add=T" of normal plots. Can I do it? How?

Comment: ggmap is meant to be used with ggplot syntax

Comment: Thank you, but I have never used ggplot. Do you mean the qplot function? I haven't found any parameter similar to 'add'. Or is it a completely different approach?

Comment: There are several helpful examples in [this vignette](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if they just add an 'add' parameter to their plot function?

Comment: Probably not - the package seems to have been designed to accommodate the idioms of `ggplot2`, which are significantly different than that of base R plots. I'm sure you could contact the authors and inquire about it, but I bet they had very good reasons for using the current interface.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the "ggplot2" package. But I'd really better contact the authors. Thanks again!